# kivy does not start in vmware windows7 desktop

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, vmware, pyinstaller

We've developed an application in Python 2.7 + kivy 1.9.1-dev1. Used PyInstaller to create an installable package. Works fine in windows7 and windows10 environments. However, when installing in a vmware - windows7 configuration we run into the following problems:

```
[INFO              ] Logger: Record log in C:\Users\Sequence\.kivy\logs\kivy_17-03-22_0.txt
[WARNING           ] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
[WARNING           ] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 14)
[INFO              ] Kivy: v1.9.1-dev1
[INFO              ] Python: v2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:19:22) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO              ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO              ] Text: Provider: sdl2
[INFO              ] Factory: 179 symbols loaded
[INFO              ] OSC: using <thread> for socket
[INFO              ] Window: Provider: sdl2
[CRITICAL          ] Window: Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
sdl2 - RuntimeError: No matching GL pixel format available
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 67, in core_select_lib
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 138, in __init__
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 722, in __init__
  File "site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 237, in create_window
  File "kivy\core\window\_window_sdl2.pyx", line 133, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window (kivy\core/window\_window_sdl2.c:2284)
  File "kivy\core\window\_window_sdl2.pyx", line 55, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.die (kivy\core/window\_window_sdl2.c:1479)

[CRITICAL          ] App: Unable to get a Window, abort.
[WARNING           ] stderr: Exception SystemExit: 1 in 'kivy.properties.dpi2px' ignored
[WARNING           ] stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "ngamain.py", line 34, in <module>
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "workflow.py", line 1089, in startWorkflow
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 802, in run
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "workflow.py", line 1081, in build
[WARNING           ] stderr: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clearcolor'
```

The problem probably relates to the OpenGL 2.0 / 32bits requirement. But I don't have any idea how to configure/solve this. Who can help or has any suggestions on how to proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have VGA driver installed on your virtual machine. Microsoft only includes OpenGL 1.x support in its drivers so try installing the lastest version.